# Simplest way to perform a case insensitive "in" check and retrieve original element?

Tags: python

Let's say a have a list of strings and a particular string:

```
particular_string = 'latitude'
list_ = ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'longitude']
```

What I want to achieve, is to perform a case insensitive check if a particular string is in the list, so now I can do:

```
list_casefolded = (list_element.casefold() for list_element in list_)
if particular_string.casefolded() in list_casefolded:
    ...
```

But at the end of the day, I still have no idea **what was the originally mapped string in the list**.

Simplest way to perform a check and retrieve the original element?

Comment: `for elem in list_:
    if particular_string.lower() == elem.lower():
        print(elem)` ?

Comment: @Rakesh he wants to know what the original string was - (before using .lower())

Comment: this will print the string I'm providing, not the found one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `list_` into the dictionary with `casefold` keys:

```
particular_string = 'latitude'
list_ = ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'longitude']

lookup = {i.casefold(): i for i in list_}

print(lookup.get(particular_string.casefold()))
# LATitude
```

Answer (score 2):

```
particular_string = 'latitude'
list_ = ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'longitude']


for element in list_:
    if particular_string.casefold()==element.casefold():
        print(element)
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for something like this:

```
search_string = 'latitude'
search_string_cf = search_string.casefold()

item_list = ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'longitude']

for item in item_list:
    item_cf = item.casefold()

    if search_string_cf == item_cf:
        print(item)
        break
```

Or more concisely:

```
search_string = 'latitude'
item_list = ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'longitude']

item = filter(lambda x: x.casefold() == search_string, item_list)

print(next(item))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 x.py
LATitude
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
particular_string = 'latitude'

list_ = ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'longitude']

lowered = [elem.casefold() for elem in list_]

print(list_[lowered.index(particular_string)])
```

Out:

```
'LATitude'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use filter? You are going to have to iterate the list anyway. Plus now you will get feedback if there are multiple different matches!

```
particular_string = 'latitude'
list_ = ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'lAtitude', 'longitude']
print(list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() == particular_string.lower(), list_)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, It can be extended for multiple inputs:-

```
>>> map = {particular_string: []}
>>> for ele in list_:
...     if ele.casefold() == particular_string:
...         map[particular_string].append(ele)
>>> map
{'latitude': ['LATitude']}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
edited = [x.lower() for x in ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'longitude']]
location = edited.index("latitude") # returns 2
```

Then you can do:

```
list_ = ['Id', 'PRICE', 'LATitude', 'longitude']
required_value = list_[location]
```